# Opacity in an animation doesn't stick

Tags: final-cut-pro-x

I'm just getting started with Final Cut Pro X and I'm following this video for a slide out animation:

I have a background square for my text as the Text moves to the right. If I set the opacity to 80%, the background looks how I want when there is no animation. Once the transition is animating though, the background is opaque and not transparent. Is there a way to get around this?

Thanks!

Comment: What did you use for the background square?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what’s the problem is.

The compound clip isn’t working that way because you have probably a “Solids” generator in it.

Ignore the step of generating the compound clip and build the sliding box and text on top of the main timeline. That should work as you want.

Comment: Yes I used a blank solids behind the text so I wouldn't just have floating text. I'd like to use it as a compound clip bc then I can reuse it in other projects but just change the text. Is that not possible? Thanks!

Comment: The way the tutorial is doing it I don’t think it will work. The time and effort is better spend elsewhere. It’s such a quick build that it shouldn’t be too time consuming to make another when you need it. If you need a copy in another project you could make a copy of all layers.